# Downloading cover art URL from Spotify and key-value observing

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm displaying a list of Spotify tracks in a table view in my application, and I'd like to download the cover art for the albums that these tracks belong to.

I'm logged in to CocoaLibSpotify, and I can play all the tracks, so that part is fine. What I can't seem to get to work is the download of the cover art. I follow the code of the SimplePlayer project, with the exception that I store the SPTrack instances in a mutable dictionary (tracksDownladingForCoverArt), since there could be many tracks downloading cover art.

So, this is what I do:

```
[[SPSession sharedSession] trackForURL:nativeSpotifyURL callback:^(SPTrack *track) {
    if (track != nil) {

        [track addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"album.cover.spotifyURL" options:0 context:NULL];
        self.tracksDownloadingForCoverArt[nativeSpotifyURL] = track;

        [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:track timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *tracks, NSArray *notLoadedTracks) {
            if ([tracks count] > 0) {
                // I don't believe I need to do anything here
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

The observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: is called once, with an old and new value of nil, but after that, nothing. However, if I follow SimplePlayer to the letter (i.e. have self.currentTrack instead of a dictionary) and register for the key path @"self.currentTrack.album.cover.spotifyURL", the observerValue... method is called twice, once with nil and once with an actual value.

What am I missing? Oh, and I register for the spotifyURL rather than the image, so I can cache the image. That way, when the user quits the app and returns later, not all the images have to be reloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behaviour — cover art isn't loaded unless you explicitly ask for it to keep data usage down. To load all the cover art, you could do this…

```
NSArray *tracksToGetArtFor = …; // Get some tracks;
[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:tracks timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedTracks, NSArray *notLoadedTracks) {

    NSArray *coverArts = [tracks valueForKey:@"album.cover"]; // Get an array of the track's covers

    [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:coverArts timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedCovers, NSArray *notLoadedCovers) {
        NSLog(@"Number of covers that're loaded: %@:", @(loadedCovers.count));
    }];
]};
```

You'll likely want a larger timeout for loading a lot of covers, since they can be fairly big.

Another approach if you don't want to use `SPAsyncLoading` for the covers is to load the tracks using `SPAsyncLoading` then KVO on each track's `album.cover` property. To force all the covers to start loading, you need to call the the `-startLoading` method of each cover. For example:

```
NSArray *tracksToGetArtFor = …; // Get some tracks;
[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:tracks timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedTracks, NSArray *notLoadedTracks) {

    NSArray *coverArts = [tracks valueForKey:@"album.cover"]; // Get an array of the track's covers

    // Trigger the -startLoading method of each cover.
    [coverArts makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(startLoading)];

]};
```

Comment: `valueForKey` should be `valueForKeyPath`

Comment: What is the data type for the album.cover?

Comment: I get an error when I retrieve a track with no album cover. How can I catch this? Error is [NSNull isLoaded].

Comment: You need to remove all instances of NSNull from your coverArts array before sending them to SPAsynLoading.

Comment: Or is it possible to just get the url of the album's cover using cocoalibspotify?